# Changing keyboard layout in UITextField causes memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uikit

I have created `UITextField` in `UITableViewCell` in my app, and I receive strange memory leak with it.

When I launch my application and tap this `UITextField` - there is no problem with it. I can type text in English, no leaks at this moment.

But when I press globe button on a keyboard to switch to another language(for instance, Russian), I receive the memory leak in `UIKeyboardInputManager`, even if I don't type any text in non-english language.

Any ideas?

Tested both in simulator and iphone.

Comment: please provide some source code.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this is an issue with iOS, not even Apple is perfect. File a bug report with Apple.

http://bugreport.apple.com